# Background image removal component

Tags: python, django, api, image-processing

I'm looking for an API/Library/Component to use in my Django app that takes an image as an input and returns the same image with transparent background. I'm looking for something smarter than ImageMagick's floodfill http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/channels/#mask_floodfill that detects the color of the background.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What is it you consider background? There may be some simple solutions using numpy arrays and logic operations over it. Keep in mind that transparent means alpha channel or palette, so your output will be either PNG or GIF.

Comment: I don't have a specific background, take this picture for example http://www.sssautomotive.com.au/images/downloads/fullsize/subaru_racer.jpg. The background may vary, I want a smart algorithm that distincts the background from the object and applies an alpha transparency. I don't expect to be perfect though, I just need to cleanup the obvious background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) you have im.save(filename, transparency=some_palette_index) for mode P images or putalpha method for RGB images.